# Is is possible to change title of `UIImagePickerController`when choosing videos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture, photo-gallery

I have open photo gallery for choosing video. Here is my code :

```
- (void)selectMediaFrom:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
     UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if (selectedMediaType == MediaVideos) {
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeVideo];
        if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
        }
    }
    else if (selectedMediaType == MediaPhotos) {
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        }
    }

    if (IS_IPHONE) {
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        });
    }
}
```

And it is always showing title of `UIImagePickerController` as **Photos**, See screenshot I have attached.

[image: imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary and imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeVideo]]

But, I have open **iPhone** default **Photos app** and check, that shows videos folder : See below

[image: Default Photos App]

Then why it is not showing **Videos** title ? Can we change it ?

Comment: in your both screenshot folder title is same : `Videos` ! What you are asking exactly ? It is not much clear what you want to achieve!

Comment: I have clearly mention, that I want to change title of screen. Please see in first screenshot.

Comment: If you just want to change title of screen then you shouldn't add another screen shots rounding videos! It's making confusion. Your question should be like `how to change title of imagepickercontroller? ` that's it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You can change the title of Navigation which you want.

Add the delegate of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

**Swift 3.0**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool){
    viewController.navigationItem.title = "Kirit Modi"
}
```

**Objective C**

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Kirit Modi"];
}
```

**See Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to adapt for my situation. Because I present my ImagePicker programmatically from another VC, I had to use similar code. I first created a variable for the presenting VC: `let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()`, and then later in the presenting VC, I used `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) { imagePickerController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "choose photo" }`. It works well. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @PhontaineJudd You can add your code in the answer also so help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. I was able to adapt for my situation. Because I present my ImagePicker programmatically from another VC, I had to use similar code.

I first created a variable for the presenting VC:

`let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()`

And then later in the presenting VC, I used:

**Swift 4**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    // change title here to something other than default "Photo"
    imagePickerController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "choose photo" 
}
```

It works well. Hope this helps someone.